# Kannel in VirtualBox VM with iPhone as modem

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, sms-gateway, gsm

I have installed kannel in a virtual machine (ubuntu 10.04).
I did not change any of the default config and tested the fakesmsc. This work fine.
When I plug my iPhone in USB, I do not see any /dev/ttyUSB showing up (I though this was how modem was mounted).
Could you please help ?

Thanks a lot,

Luc

Answer (score 2):

Yes but I don't know if iPhones are supported to work as modems or supported by kannel, this is a list of supported modems but I think it's outdated meaning more phones are supported:

http://www.kannel.org/compatibility.shtml

good luck